# Customer delete before observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer

In Magento from admin panel we can delete customer and ca do mass delete of customers. Is there any way to run an **`observer`** before deleting customer we can get the customer id ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `around` plugin here.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository">
        <plugin name="customer_delete_action" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\DeleteCustomer" />
    </type>

</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/DeleteCustomer.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class DeleteCustomer
{
    public function aroundDeleteById(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $customerId
    ) {
        // You can add your logic here
        if ($customerId == 10) {
            // Play here
        }

        // It will proceed ahead with the default delete function        
        $result = $proceed($customerId);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using event `customer_delete_before`
And in the observer, you can get the object data using

```
$object = $observer->getData('object');
```

And you can get the customer id using

```
$object->getEntityId();
```