# Event after remove customer Magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, event-observer

How to create an event on customer remove from backend.?
what is the name of the event? 
I need to remove customer's data from my custom table after removing a customer from the backend.

Comment: when the admin deletes the customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution already shared here

[Customer delete before observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239415/customer-delete-before-observer)

Please try using plugin.

Comment: In this case, while the linked answer works. I would recommend using an `after` plugin rather than the suggested `around`. Since we don't need to terminate further executions. See the following link for more details about it. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#around-methods