# What event should I use for Customer delete observer in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer, customer-account

I'm very new to Magento 2.3, so I can't find a list of all the events that are related to user accounts. I need to create observers for user deleted, user updated (any information in account) and user created. Could I get some help please? :)

I found quite old information about events customer_save_after and customer_delete_after, but I'm not sure they are still used in 2019.

Also, if you could provide a link to a list with all (current) events in Magento 2.3, it would be very useful. Thank you.

Comment: You can refer this link [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239415/customer-delete-before-observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239415/customer-delete-before-observer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "customer_delete_after" event in Magento 2.3.

```
<event name="customer_delete_after">
    <observer name="ddg_remove_contact" instance="Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Observer\Customer\RemoveContact"/>
</event>
```

This event is used in Magento's dotmailer module in the vendor.

Below is the link for the event list in Magento 2.

> https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html

Comment: Thank you. I actually experience something strange in customers admin area, it doesn't allow me to edit or delete customers (I'm working in developer mode and log in as admin). But after I resolve this issue, will try your suggestion.

Comment: It would be more helpful to know where Magento is dispatching this event, I assume some abstract class doing "[model]_delete_after" but I can't get this my observer to execute for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can hook into customer_save_after_data_object event where it will provide previous customer object and new object as observer parameters
for deletion you can use customer_delete_after